# Override template file to theme vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides

I want to override this template file to my theme

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

here is my theme path :

> app/design/frontend/Custom/luma_child/

can anyone help here how to override this file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy this file

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

here in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Custom/luma_child/Amazon_Payment/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

You can customize your file here.

You can find any module name in it's `module.xml` file, in your case you can find that here.

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/etc/module.xml

and you can use that in your child theme.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Ok thanks let me try

Comment: Okay let me know if it will works for you then. :)

Comment: yes worked +1   thanks

Comment: Can you please approve my answer. If this helps you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can override from

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/Custom/luma_child/Amazon_Payment/templates/widget/resetpassword.phtml

Comment: Ok thanks let me try this